# Shared prefernces не работают после закрытия приложения

Tags: java, android

После сохранения String в  Shared prefernces, я получаю данные в другой активити.
И все в принципе работает. НО!!! Если убить процесс приложения, или перезагрузить телефон, при получении данных из Shared prefernces приложение остановлено.
Все в основном ответы сводятся к "не забудь сделать editor.commit()".

Я создал новое приложение, проще некуда, но результат тотже.
MainActivity

```
package com.example.nes.test;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements             View.OnClickListener {
Button btnext,SavePref;
public static SharedPreferences sPref;
String data;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnext = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnext);
    btnext.setOnClickListener(this);
    SavePref = (Button)findViewById(R.id.SavePref);
    SavePref.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btnext:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);break;
        case R.id.SavePref:
            sPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
            ed.putString(data,"aasdjf");
            ed.commit();break;

    }
}
}
```

Mainactivity2

```
package com.example.nes.test;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
SharedPreferences sPref;
String data;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    sPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());;
    String database = sPref.getString(data, "");
    Toast.makeText(this, database, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


}
```

manifest

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Main2Activity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main2" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: а смотрели что в логах пишут?

Comment: Добавил лог в теле

Comment: У вас NPE  тут - com.example.nes.app.onResume.onCreate(onResume.java:73) Что на 73 строчке?

Comment: на 73 я просто начинаю работать с String database. А он  NULL, вот и ругается       ArrayList<String> DB = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(database.split(",")));

Comment: Оно работает,но только если не убивать процесс APP

Comment: Ну так значит проблема то не в SharedPrefernces, а в базе данных

Comment: Замените работу с базой просто на присвоение к-л строки. Должно будет заработать и тем самым показать, что дело в базе данных.

Comment: Я пробовал просто вставить текст в  SharedPrefernces и потом получить его. Результат тот же

Comment: sPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
        ed.clear();
        ed.putString(data,"aasdasdas");
        ed.commit();

Comment: sPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);;
        String database = sPref.getString(data, null);
        Toast.makeText(onResume.this, database, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: После сворачивания приложения все хорошо, после убивания процесса приходит пустой Toast

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
SharedPreferences sPref;
String data;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    sPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());;
    String database = sPref.getString(data, "");
    Toast.makeText(this, database, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

в этом коде переменная data не задана. в первом activity тоже. поставьте в обоих activity `String data="KEY_DATA";`

Comment: Да!  Спасибо огромное. Тупая и обидная ошибка! Евгений большое Вам спасибо!  Ошибка была именно в этом. Вот только не понятно по какому принципу оно-то все таки работало пока не закрывал процесс.

Comment: @СергейЧумаков, если ответ решил заявленную в вопросе проблему - то хорошим тоном на сайте считается отметить его принятым (нажав на галочку слева от ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте воспользоваться дефолтными preference

```
pref=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

UPD:

Попробуйте убрать

> ed.clear();

ибо непонятно зачем он вызывается и вместо null значение по умолчанию поставить ""

> sPref.getString(data, "");

Обновление 1

Попробуйте в манифест разрешения добавить

```
 <manifest ...>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   ...
  </manifest>
```

Comment: пробовал уже, тот же результат

Comment: не помогает не ed.clear(); не sPref.getString(data, "");

Answer (score 1):

Что бы все наверняка работало, храните статическую ссылку на SharedPreferences в классе, который наследуется от Application(OnCreate методе можно инициализировать их). Установите этот класс в манифесте. Потом добавте метод get для получения этих SharedPreferences. А потом просто везде ее используйте, тогда у вас точно будет достут к одним и темже SharedPreferences.

Вот пример класса. Не забудьте только добавить его в манифест.

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
private static SharedPreferences m_sharedPreferences;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    m_sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
}

public static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(){
    return m_sharedPreferences;
}
```

}

Comment: Изменил код в изначальном вопросе. Результат тот-же.

Comment: @СергейЧумаков, вы не сделали то, что я написал)) Вам следует в onCreate один раз инициализировать ShPref